# Why does my TV blank out for a moment when I fullscreen a HDR video file?

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player

I've set up a Ryzen 5/ 3rd generation small form factor / NUC type machine as a HTPC. I'm running windows 11 on it at the moment. I'm using VLC 3.0.18 vetinari as a video player

Its connected to a HDR capable UHD OLED TV (Its a Prism+ 55AL), , and I play video files using VLC. When I play a HDR capable video clip there's a momentary HDR OSD message, and when I full screen VLC, usually by pressing the F button the screen blanks out for a second, playback pauses, and things go perfectly otherwise.

Its a minor annoyance - it plays things perfectly otherwise, but why *is* windows/VLC pausing for a moment?

System specs are as below - Its perfectly capable of outputting UHD and HDR certainly works

[image]

[image]

And the onboard graphics are here

Comment: Have you compared the display mode (resolution, HDR status, refresh rate) before and after? Maybe VLC is switching to the video's "native" settings.

Comment: Resolution is UHD all the way. I see the HDR osd message when the PC source is selected. I have no idea how to check refresh rate while full screened

Comment: With my Panasonic TV, I can press the _i_ button on the remote and it’ll display both resolution and refresh rate (as “60p” or “24p” or the like) in the upper left corner. Pretty sure most TVs have this information available somewhere.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fghXE.png not very useful there. I got this when I was playing video fullscreen too so no obvious differences.